# How to add multiple input from one field in django model

Tags: django, python-3.x, database, model

I have this models.py code where I want to get multiple values/file from single field without creating another table just for images.

Currently I am just repeating these field

```
class contentimage(models.Model):
content = models.ForeignKey(element, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

titleimg1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
image1 = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='media/')
img1description = models.TextField()

titleimg2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
image2 = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='media/')
img2description = models.TextField()

titleimg3 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
image3 = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='media/')
img3description = models.TextField()

titleimg4 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
image4 = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='media/')
img4description = models.TextField()

titleimg5 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
image5 = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='media/')
img5description = models.TextField()
```

An optimal output will be an input field in django admin where a plus sign can add multiple images
It would be really very helpful if someone can just guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the images into Inlines. First give them their own model class:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    content = models.ForeignKey(contentimage, on_delete=PROTECT). # this is what connect the two models
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='media/')
    description = models.TextField()
```

Then register the class in the admin:

```
class ImageInlineAdmin(admin.InlineModelAdmin):
    extra = 0
    model = Image
```

And then register the inline in your contentimage admin with a line:

```
inlines = [ImageInlineAdmin]
```